# Can an executable file display a website by precising the url? Can I run a specific website on my own .exe file?

Tags: python, database, web, executable

I am hosting a dynamic website on Infinity Free and creating a game with Python that (i want it) to be linked with it (eg. accounts, ingame data,...). I want it to be linked to the Infinity Free database but Infinity Free does not allow external files to access the SQL database (even with connexion parameters). I don't want the game to be launched on Chrome, since it is kind of pejorative. So is it possible to open a webpage with my own executable file (.exe) instead of Chrome/Mozilla/etc. by precising the url of the site so that Infinity Free thinks that it is not external. I need the game to access to the database (accounts and more) and as it is a multplayer : the data of the players is stored in a temporary SQL table.

I really don't know how to do it and even if it is possible. I did not find any relvent help on the Internet. I tried to run a PHP file that is on Infinity Free from a Python script on browser but Infinity Free blocked the import of PHP & HTML.
I seached for a whole day and I am exhausted, can someone help me?

Comment: This is quite challenging and I am afraid this can't be answered in a single thread on stackoverflow. You would have to create a custom mini-browser using Python with libraries like PyQt or PySide which includes the WebEngine. Your game can launch this browser pointing to your Infinity Free website, and Infinity Free would see this as a regular browser request.

Comment: While I have not looked into the details of that provider, it is likely the case that you can build an service that host an API to drive your game. At that point, you could implement the client in any technology that consumed your api.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make what I wanted.
The trick was to create a mini Web-browser using the PyQt5 library. I found a lot of tutos on YouTube and it worked perfectly well.
I used this tutorial to make it. I put the link bellow in case it can help someone ‍♂️
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-5bZ8EoKu4